# How can I estimate the probability of coin flips with python?

Tags: python, simulation, probability

I have created a program that simulates a specific number of coin flips. The simulation flips the coin 8 times, it is currently running the simulation 10000 times. I want to find out specific probabilities using the simulation. For example, what is the probability of getting exactly 2 tails in the 8 flips based on the 10000 results. I have a brief idea of how to do this, however I am not sure how to isolate exactly two results. The coin also has a random bias set to it.

Code:

```
# Random numbers:
coin_flip_seed = random_num

bias_choices = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]

coin_flip_bias = bias_choices[coin_flip_seed % 4]

# Main simulation:
np.random.seed(coin_flip_seed)

results = [['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S']]

tests = 10000

for j in range(tests):
    flips = []
   
    for i in range(8):
        flip_result = np.random.binomial(1,coin_flip_bias)
     
        if flip_result == 1:
            flips = np.append(flips, 'H')
        else:
            flips = np.append(flips, 'T')
   
    results = np.append(results, [flips], axis = 0)

results = results[1:]

print(results[4])
# Probability of getting exactly 2 tails:
num_2T = 0

for k in range(tests):
    if results[k,2] == 'T':
        num_2T += 1
        

print("The probability of getting exactly 2 tails is: ", num_2T/tests)
```

At the moment I am only able to find out the probability of getting 1 tail on the 3rd flip.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want an answer to the question "what is the probability to get *k* heads in *n* coin flips with probability *p* to get a head?", or do you specifically want to know how to simulate it? I ask because simulation isn't necessary and the probability can be computed directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I set the random seed:

```
coin_flip_seed = 111
```

And run your code, I get:

```
num_2T
1980
```

Your `results` object is a numpy array, so to get the same result above you can just sum the number of entries in the 3rd column that are 'T' :

```
np.sum(results[:,2] == 'T')
1980
```

Likewise, if we think in terms of the matrix you have now, what you need are the number of rows that have exactly 2 'T'. This gives you for each row, the number of 'T':

```
np.sum(results=='T',axis=1)
```

And we just count how many of them are 2:

```
np.sum(np.sum(results=='T',axis=1)==2)
2933
```

Lastly as a comment, most likely you can simulate `results` using np.random.choice and providing the shape of your simulation. Should give you something similar.